# A letter's misplaced? But there are only numbers!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

3 + 4 = 7

4 + 4 > 3

3 + 3 = ?

Which letter is misplaced? (Note: These letters are in the English language.)

Hint 1:

> cryptarithm

Comment: A day has passed. Someone should have said that the answer is 6.

Comment: The answer is not 6. It’s a letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the misplaced letter is

> V

Reasoning

> Using the hint that we are looking at a cryptarithm, let's replace the numbers with their spelling and solve as if we have a cryptarithm, i.e,
>  THREE + FOUR = SEVEN and FOUR + FOUR > THREE.
>  Clearly, from the first equation, it must be that S is 1 more than T and, from the second equation, T can only be 1 (since it is less than double a four digit number) so S=2.
>  From the first equation again, either E+U is congruent to E or E-1 (if we carry over) modulo 10 which makes U either 0 or 9.
>  If U is 0, then the possibilities for (E,R,N) are (3,4,7), (3,5,8), (3,6,9), (4,5,9), (4,3,7), (5,3,8), (6,3,9) or (5,4,9).
>  (E,R,N) = (3,4,7) gives no solutions for the first equation.
>  (E,R,N) = (3,5,8) gives two solutions for the first equation - 16533 + 7405 = 23938 or 17533 + 6405 = 23938 - although in both cases FOUR + FOUR < THREE.
>  (E,R,N) = (3,6,9) gives two solutions for the first equation - 15633 + 7806 = 23439 and 17633 + 5806 = 23439 - although in both cases FOUR + FOUR < THREE.
>  (E,R,N) = (4,5,9) gives two solutions for the first equation - 16544 + 7805 = 24349 and 17544 + 6805 = 24349 - although in both cases FOUR + FOUR < THREE.
>  (E,R,N) = (4,3,7) gives no solutions.
>  (E,R,N) = (5,3,8) gives two solutions - 19355 + 6403 = 25758 and **16355 + 9403 = 25758** - and only in the second case do we have FOUR + FOUR > THREE.
>  (E,R,N) = (6,3,9) gives no solutions.
>  (E,R,N) = (5,4,9) gives no solutions.
>  If U is 9, then the possibilites for (E,R,N) are (3,7,0), (4,6,0), (6,8,4), (7,8,5), (7,3,0), (6,4,0), (8,6,4) or (8,7,5).
>  Going through these case by case we find that none of them gives us a solution to the first equation.
>  Hence the only solution to the cryptarithm for the first two equations is
>  (E,F,H,N,O,R,S,T,U,V) = (5,9,6,8,4,3,2,1,0,7)
>  in which case
>  THREE + THREE = 16355 + 16355 = 32710 = RSVTU
>  which is almost **RSTUV** (as the letters appear in the alphabet) but **V** has been placed in the middle - it's misplaced!

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: damn me. i did the exact same thing, but for whatever reason forgot i had to find a MISPLACED letter and not MISSING.